# when select cursor sql get force close

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

this my method highscore

```
public void highscore(){

        Cursor gethighscorealter = highscoreDB.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(TIME) FROM HIGHSCORE3;"
                   , null);
        gethighscorealter.moveToFirst();
        if(gethighscorealter!=null){
            timer= gethighscorealter.getInt(gethighscorealter.getColumnIndex("TIME"));
            move = gethighscorealter.getInt(gethighscorealter.getColumnIndex("MOVE"));
            grid = gethighscorealter.getInt(gethighscorealter.getColumnIndex("GRID"));
            highscoreview();
        }
    }
```

this my log cat

```
06-02 13:30:38.599: E/AndroidRuntime(32416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 13:30:38.599: E/AndroidRuntime(32416): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
06-02 13:30:38.599: E/AndroidRuntime(32416):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
06-02 13:30:38.599: E/AndroidRuntime(32416):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:507)
06-02 13:30:38.599: E/AndroidRuntime(32416):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:574)
06-02 13:30:38.599: E/AndroidRuntime(32416):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
06-02 13:30:38.599: E/AndroidRuntime(32416):    at skripsi.slidame.PuzzleActivity.highscore(PuzzleActivity.java:253)
06-02 13:30:38.599: E/AndroidRuntime(32416):    at skripsi.slidame.PuzzleActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(PuzzleActivity.java:131)
```

they said row 0 col - 1??i cant understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is that your query is only returning the TIME column. You have to modify your query to say `SELECT MIN(TIME), MOVE, GRID FROM HIGHSCORE3;` to return all the columns you are looking for.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: thx i got it, when i tested on w3schools.com i see just 1 column selected, so im using order by ASC and i got the minimum value in that table, but that now im thinking about get minimum value with 2 column parameter `TIME` and `MOVE`

Comment: i got it, `select min(time),min(move) from highscore3` 
but,i cant call name column as usual, must `getnameindex(0)`;couse when i see in w3school.com column name change to `expr1000`

Answer (score 0):

Please change the name of column `time` from table and retrieve data after that. Because this is the key that is already stored inside the `database schema`. Please change the name of column and check again everything. I hope it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I thick your cursor do not get count then throw exception,

```
Cursor gethighscorealter = highscoreDB.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(TIME) FROM HIGHSCORE3;"
               , null);

    if(gethighscorealter.getCount() > 0){
        gethighscorealter.moveToFirst();
        timer= gethighscorealter.getInt(gethighscorealter.getColumnIndex("TIME"));
        move = gethighscorealter.getInt(gethighscorealter.getColumnIndex("MOVE"));
        grid = gethighscorealter.getInt(gethighscorealter.getColumnIndex("GRID"));
        highscoreview();
        gethighscorealter.close();

    }
```